# Need to find and open a USB serial device on linux

Tags: linux, usb, libusb, udev, usbserial

I'm writing a small C application to run on my (Linux) QNAP NAS that will talk to an Arduino (I have no difficulty with any of the USB code for the arduino).  (The arduino has a trusted application on it that accepts text commands via USB serial.)

My wish was to find it using the USB vendor/product IDs (only half implemented at the moment).  What I have so far (see below) works quite nicely in that it does find the device.

```
// runs on NAS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <usb.h>

main () {
  struct usb_bus *bus;
  struct usb_device *dev;
  usb_init();
  usb_find_busses();
  usb_find_devices();
  for (bus = usb_busses; bus; bus = bus->next) {
    for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next) {
      printf("Trying %s/%s\n", bus->dirname, dev->filename);
      printf("\tVendor = 0x%04x\n", dev->descriptor.idVendor);
      printf("\tBus = 0x%03x\n", bus->location);
      printf("\tFile = %s\n", dev->filename);
      if (dev->descriptor.idVendor==0x403) {
        printf("\t  HEY, THIS IS MINE!\n");
        usb_dev_handle *handle = usb_open(dev);
        printf("\t   HANDLE 0x%08x\n", (int) handle);
        //printf(handle, "1,5,62,75\n");
        usb_close(handle);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The trouble is that now I want to send/receive a little bit of text with the device and I don't know how to do that.

I have expected I should be generating a device name from something in the usb_device struct and then open it like a file (like one would do on Windows).

If that's correct, I need to know the correct way to find out the device name...

I believe I'm using libusb.

I happen to know that -- as currently configured/connected -- it's ttyUSB0 but I'd like to know that using code.

thank you!

Comment: I recall reading similar Qs on this topic. searching for `[c] libusb vendor id` shows 6 possible threads. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [libusbp](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp).  It is a C library with a C++ wrapper, and there is example code showing how to get the name of a serial port based on the vendor ID and product ID of the USB device:

https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/blob/master/examples/port_name/port_name.cpp

Comment: Thank you for this; it looked promising but my weak linux/gcc skills & experience are making it quite difficult to get things working.   "libusbp.hpp:  no such file or directory".  I would have thought that by providing -lLibUSBP -rpath=/src/LibUSBP -L/src/LibUSBP command line parameters would make that work.  Clearly, I don't know enough about gcc.

Comment: Linux filenames are case sensitive and you got the case wrong in your command.  See the libusbp README, which discusses how to install it and compile a program that uses it.

Comment: Thank you for the extra information.  Couldn't get it working; clearly my lack of understanding of gcc and how it finds libraries is quite weak.  I know too little to fool around with this stuff.  I have decided to completely skip this part.

Comment: I have checked out `libusbp` and turns out it does use `libudev` for looking up the serial port names on Linux

Answer (score 0):

`libusb` is a library used for low level communication with USB devices. But when your communication is limited just to reading device's USB descriptor - `libusb` is not the best tool.

Linux systems use `udev` subsystem to manage hot-plug devices. `udev` reads descriptors of all plugged USB devices and stores them in its database. `libudev` is the library that you should use to get such info like device names of enumerated devices. In your case you need to remember that `usb_device` and `usb_interface` are separate things - only the latter would have the `tty` device file assigned to it.

Alternatively you could just use `udev` config to assign a constant device name to your specific device. So you would not have to be looking for it.